# StackExchange.Redis in Azure Functions not working

Tags: azure-functions, stackexchange.redis

I've created a super simple `Azure Function` that uses `Dependency Injection` to utilize my shared libraries.

The function is working fine locally on my dev machine but when I publish it to Azure, I get an error that states `StackExchange.Redis` has no endpoints specified -- see below:
[image]

I read somewhere that this could be due to `ConnectionMultiplexerr` not being `static`. Here's the code for my `RedisCache` client in my shared library:

```
public class RedisCache
{
   private static IDatabase _cache;
   private static ConnectionMultiplexer connection;
   private Dictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _locks;

   public RedisCache(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      var host = configuration["redisHost"];
      var key = configuration["redisKey"];
      if (_cache == null)
      {
         connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{host},abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password={key}");
        _cache = connection.GetDatabase();
      }
      _locks = new Dictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
   }

   public async Task<T> GetObjectAsync<T>(string key)
   {
       var serializedCachedData = await _cache.StringGetAsync(key);

       if (!serializedCachedData.HasValue)
         return default(T);

       return JsonUtils.Deserialize<T>(serializedCachedData.ToString());
   }

}
```

And here's how I handle creating a singleton instance of my `RedisCache` client in the `Startup.cs` in my `Azure Function` app:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
   public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
   {
      var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
         .Build();


      builder.Services.AddSingleton(new RedisCache(configuration));
    }
}
```

Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `appsettings.json` is not deployed properly. Can you check your application settings from the `Azure Portal` to verify if your settings are uploaded. Also a better way to `SetBasePath` is to use the `ExecutionContext`. Eg code below

#### Using Execution Context

```
var executioncontextoptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
         .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;

var currentDirectory = executioncontextoptions.AppDirectory;
```

#### Using Assembly

```
var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var currentDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(binDirectory, ".."));
```

Also you are missing the `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` on your `ConfigurationBuilder`. It should be done like this

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(currentDirectory )
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

Comment: All your suggestions were right on and now it's working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome @Sam glad to help